# checking database credentials using PDO showing error

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

Making a login and validation form using PDO , Here is database code which is showing connection to my database which is running correctly and have connection with localhost database.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=filesystem", $username, $password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

and now  i am making connection to  open a page after validating from database based on correct username and password , Here is code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $user=!empty($_POST['user']) ? trim($_POST['user']) :null ;
    $password=!empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) :null;
    $sql="select * from users where user='$user' and password='$password'";
    if($stmt=$con->query( $sql))
    {
        if($stmt->fetchColumn()>0)
        {
            $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $u_name=$row['user'];
            $u_password=$row['password'];
            if($user==$u_name && $password==$u_password)
            {
                if(isset($_POST['remember']))
                {
                    setcookie('user',$user,time()+60*60*7);
                    setcookie('password',$password,time()+60*60*7);
                }
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                echo "<script> window.location.assign('../index.php'); </script>"; 
                exit();        
            } else {
                echo "nothing";
            }
        } else {
            echo"<script>alert('incorrect user name or password')</script>";
            echo "<script> window.location.assign('login.php'); </script>"; 
        }
    }
}
```

output of this code is showing nothing which is **output** of `else` while checking password from form and database here `if($user==$u_name && $password==$u_password)` and input credential are right but still showing this error ,some body Help me Please.

Comment: You are wide wide open to SQL injection and other security risks. Unencrypted passwords in both the database and cookies? That's taking it to the next level. If this is for a production application, I think you should consider using a third party authentication library

Comment: Use bind parameters instead of concatenating a string, use password_hash and password_verify to check the password and use session instead of password in a cookie for session management. Changing to do that will be writing all the code for you, so you will probably not get anyone here to do it for you. But if you have problems with any of those parts many members here will be ready to help out with tips

Comment: @rypskar while making  with bind parameter still showing same out put and yes also tried `password_verify`  still same output  which is **nothing** and my sql  for password store using `AES_DECRYPT(AES_ECRYPT('password','key'),'key')`

Comment: You need to store the password using https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php. You should not store the password in plaintext, using two way encryption or a simple hash. You are encrypting it and then decrypting it before storing, so basically storing it in plain text. Try to update your question with the new code where you use bind parameters and proper password handling if it still fails. The problem is probably that you store the password using one function, and don't use the matching function to verify the password